# How to all delete record from array using index position based on condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having records like below in array:

```
$scope.skills = [];

$scope.skills['et']= s1
$scope.skills['et']= s2
$scope.skills['et']= s3

$scope.skills['gf']= t1
$scope.skills['gf']= t2
$scope.skills['gf']= t3

$scope.skills['po']= b1
$scope.skills['po']= b2
$scope.skills['po']= b3
```

Now I want to delete all records from array based on below value:

```
$scope.value ='gf';
```

Now I would like to delete all records from array whose index is other than  'gf':

So skills array should contain only record of 'gf' like below:

Expected output:

```
$scope.skills['gf']= t1
$scope.skills['gf']= t2
$scope.skills['gf']= t3
```

Comment: You are not using the array as an array. Giving it non-natural answer keys makes it basicly behave like an object. Besides that, you seem to overwrite the value over and over again.

Comment: @MoeSattler: my array is associative array in which I am dynamically creating index with et,gf etc storing corresponding skills .so that was just an example which I shown you.

Comment: I suggest that since all of the answers below were unsatisfactory, this question can be closed under the official 'Unclear' reason: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking_.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to loop over all of the keys in the array object and delete the ones you don't want.

```js
for(var k in Object.keys($scope.skills)){
    if(k !== "gf"){
        delete $scope.skills[k];
    }
}
```

As a side note for every assignment of the key you are overwriting the value so after the following

```js
$scope.skills['gf']= t1
$scope.skills['gf']= t2
$scope.skills['gf']= t3
```

the value of `$scope.skills['gf']` will be the value of the variable `t3`.

Comment: With this condition this is the match : 0 != 'gf'  which is not matching and hence records except gf are not getting removed

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something conceptually wrong with your example. Assigning multiply values to the same property will override previous assignments.

Anyway, if you only need a single property from an object you can create a new object with only that property:

```
$scope.skills = $scope.skills['gf'];
```

Comment: my array is associative array in which I am dynamically creating index with et,gf etc storing corresponding skills .so that was just an example which I shown you.so data are correct

Comment: Yeah, that's fine but assigning are['gf'] twice will overwrite the previous values. In JS, these are called just simple objects or maps, people don't usually talk about assoc arrays here.

Comment: But I am doing something like this:$scope.skills['qf']=response.skills.so here this response.skills is the data coming from server.like wise same for po and et.i hope you got my point.so this is how I am creating array.now tell me how my values are overwriting

Comment: In this example, they don't overwrite each other but in your original example they do. Just try to run that code in a console. But my answer is still the same as above. Each key is unique, so if you want to filter to a specific one, just access that element of the map.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the structure of the "array" to be able to store multiple items with the same key.

Example:

```
$scope.skills = [];

$scope.skills.push({key: 'et', value: 's1'});
$scope.skills.push({key: 'et', value: 's2'});
$scope.skills.push({key: 'et', value: 's3'});

$scope.skills.push({key: 'gf', value: 't1'});
$scope.skills.push({key: 'gf', value: 't2'});
$scope.skills.push({key: 'gf', value: 't3'});

$scope.skills.push({key: 'po', value: 'b1'});
$scope.skills.push({key: 'po', value: 'b2'});
$scope.skills.push({key: 'po', value: 'b3'});
```

Now you can delete like this:

```
$scope.keyToDelete = 'gf';

for(var i = $scope.skills.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if($scope.skills[i].key === $scope.keyToDelete) {
        $scope.skills.splice(i, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry my array structure is not like this.my array is associative araay like dictionary

Comment: So why don't you change it so that you can do what you want? And as it has been stated earlier your example is a bit confusing since you override your previous assignments.